# RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation:

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, in-place

I am using an LSTM to summarize a trajectory as shown below:

```
class RolloutEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(RolloutEncoder, self).__init__()
        self._input_size = (
            2048 + 1
        )  # deter_state + imag_reward; fix and use config["deter_dim"] + 1
        self._hidden_size = config["rollout_enc_size"]
        self._lstm = nn.LSTM(self._input_size, self._hidden_size, bias=True)

    def forward(self, traj):
        features = traj["features_pred"]
        rewards = traj["reward_pred"].unsqueeze(1)
        input = torch.cat((features, rewards), dim=2)
        encoding, (h_n, c_n) = self._lstm(input)
        code = h_n.squeeze(0)
        return code
```

My training loop is something like:

```
encoder = RolloutEncoder(config)
for e in range(episodes):
      for step in range(steps):
            print(f"Step {steps})
            # calc traj
            code = encoder(traj)
            # some operations that do not modify code but only concat it with some other tensor
            # calc loss
            opt.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
```

On running, I get this error:

```
Step 0
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Step 4
Step 5
Step 6
Step 7
Step 8
Step 9
Step 10
Step 11
Step 12
Step 13
Step 14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/main.py", line 351, in <module>
    agent_loss.backward()
  File "/home/.conda/envs/abc/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 245, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "/user/.conda/envs/abc/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 145, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [16, 2049]] is at version 8; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

On setting the anomaly_detection to True, it point to this line in the encoder definition:

```
encoding, (h_n, c_n) = self._lstm(input)
```

This is a very common error but I am not using any inplace operation. And the error occurs after running some steps successfully which is really weird. On inspecting, I found that the  [16, 2049] tensor is one of the weights of the LSTM. I also tried using dummy random tensors in place of `features` and `rewards` but the error persists, suggesting that the traj calculation has nothing to do with this error. What might be the reason for this error?

Comment: Its not allowed to write everything in the forward method. Your calculations must be derivable. In your forward function you are doing some slicing which is not derivable. Try to pass "features_pred" and "reward_pred" as two separate arguments into the forward method and avoid passing arguments using dictionaries or other non-pytorch data structures.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that, but the error still persists. I figured out why it's happening after certain number of steps though and that part can be ignored. For each step, I am sampling from a buffer that contains a mix of "code"s that have been calculated using the LSTM and others which have simply been randomly initialised - so the error doesn't show up when a code from the latter category is sampled